# Codeigniter passing dynamic data from controller to view. And Mapping values to controller array variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get the array from controller to views which is dynamic.

Suppose,

### Controller

```
 $a = array(array('category_id'=>'3', 'name'=>'car'),array('category_id'=> '5', 'name'=>'bike'));
 $data['category'] = $a;
 foreach($a as $val){
     $data[$val['name']] = $this->home_model->get_product($val['category_id']);
 }
 $this->load->view('main',$data);
```

### View (main.php)

```
 foreach($category as $val){
    foreach($val['name'] as $value){     //undefined variable passed to foreach, But when I var_dump variable are printed in controller but cannot get in views. How to map the value, to value that is passed from controller.

    }
 }
```

Now the $data array in controller will be:

```
 array (size=6)
'Car' =>  
 array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[31]
      public 'frontend_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'sub_category_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'category_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'Car' (length=3)
      public 'slug' => string 'car' (length=3)
      public 'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'status' => string '1' (length=1)
```

When I loop through `$category` in the view then, I can get car value as

```
  foreach($category as $val) {
      $name = $val['name'];            //prints car
      foreach($name as $value) {       //how to map $name to the 'car' array that is passed from controller. It say invalid argument supplied for foreach

      }
  }
```

Comment: because car is not a array

Comment: @user254153 Can you clear bit more. Im unclear in `$data[$val['name']] = $this->home_model->get_product($val['category_id']);` this and whats you need in view as output. Please explain

Comment: Okey i will edit the question.

Comment: @user254153 show dumped values as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `$` before `$val['name']`. See below code

**On your View**

```
foreach($category as $val)
{
    foreach($$val['name'] as $value){     

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array `$a` should be like,

```
$a[0] = array('category_id'=>'3', 'name'=>'car');
$a[1] = array('category_id'=>'5', 'name'=>'bike');

$data['category'] = $a;
```

Try this

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write. That but I had already passed the data. I will edit question.

Comment: try to print $a array in your controller. and see how the array looks like

Comment: array in controller are displayed as normal as it should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Your **controller** should be:-

```
 $res= $data = [];
 $a = array(array('category_id'=>'3', 'name'=>'car'),array('category_id'=> '5', 'name'=>'bike'));
 foreach($a as $val){
     $res[$val['name']] = $this->home_model->get_product($val['category_id']);
 }
 $data['category'] = $res;
 $this->load->view('main',$data);
```

Your **view** should be:-

```
 foreach($data['category'] as $val){
    foreach($val['name'] as $value){     
         // do your stuff
    }
 }
```

Comment: It didn't worked. $data['category'] cannot be accessed in view.

Answer (score 0):

I'h tested code with your data.  Its fine. So this should work

## My Testing Code

```
$a = array(
        array('category_id'=>'3', 'name'=>'car'),
        array('category_id'=> '5', 'name'=>'bike')
    );
$data['category'] = $a;
foreach($a as $val)
{
    $name = $val['name'];
    // $category_id = $this->home_model->get_product($val['category_id']);
    $category_id = $val['category_id']+5;

    $NewVal[] = array(
                    'name' => $name, 
                    'category_id' => $category_id
                );

}
print_r($NewVal);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => car [category_id] => 8 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => bike [category_id] => 10 ) )
```

---

## In Your case -  as solution

**In Controller**

```
$a = array(
        array('category_id'=>'3', 'name'=>'car'),
        array('category_id'=> '5', 'name'=>'bike')
    );
$data['category'] = $a;
foreach($a as $val)
{
    $name = $val['name'];
    $category_id = $this->home_model->get_product($val['category_id']);

    $NewVal[] = array(
                    'name' => $name, 
                    'category_id' => $category_id
                );
}

$data['category_new'] = $NewVal;
```

**In View**

```
foreach ($categorys_new as $category) {
    print_r($category);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: @user254153 Check  this out

Comment: Accepted answer is short and working. Thank you for the help.